# Why do these two methods of counting words differ significantly?

Tags: c, regex, text, scanf, text-parsing

I wrote a program that allows a user to find the number of instances of a word or collection of words in any text file. The user can enter something like this in the command line:

```
$ ./wordCount Mars TripToMars.txt
```

to search for the number of instances of the word "Mars" in the book Trip To Mars, or

```
$ ./wordCount -f collectionOfSearchWords.txt TripToMars.txt
```

to search for the number of instances of several words on individual lines in collectionOfSearchWords.txt.

To ensure that the program was correct, I used the grep commands:

```
$ grep -o 'Mars' TripToMars.txt | wc -w
```

and

```
$ grep -o -w 'Mars' TripToMars.txt | wc -w
```

The first command finds the number of instances of the word anywhere, which would include terms like "Marsa", "Marseen", "Marses", etc., while the second command finds only instances of "Mars" as a standalone word, which would include trailing punctuation such as "Mars.", "Mars!", "Mars?", etc.

Both grep commands return 49 as the number of instances of "Mars" in the book.

When I use the code in the while loop below (for simplicity, I'm only including the relevant code), the program returns 49. Awesome!

```
FILE *textToSearch;
char *readMode = "r";

int count;
char nextWord[100];
char d;

textToSearch = fopen(argVector[argCount-1], readMode);
if (textToSearch == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s to be searched\n", argVector[argCount-1]);
    return 1;
} else {
    while (fscanf(textToSearch, "%*[^a-zA-Z]"), fscanf(textToSearch, "%80[a-zA-Z]", nextWord) > 0) { 

        // increment the counter if the word is a match
        if (strcmp(nextWord, argVector[word]) == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I substitute this while loop for the previous one, the program returns 17.

```
while(1) {
    d = fscanf(textToSearch, "%s", nextWord);
    if (d == EOF) break;

    // increment the counter if the word is a match
    if (strcmp(nextWord, argVector[word]) == 0) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

So, what's the big difference between

```
while (fscanf(textToSearch, "%*[^a-zA-Z]"), fscanf(textToSearch, "%80[a-zA-Z]", nextWord) > 0) {}
```

and

```
while(1) {
    d = fscanf(textToSearch, "%s", nextWord);
    if (d == EOF) break;
}
```

?

**EDIT**:

I added this code:

```
if (strcmp(nextWordDict, nextWord) == 0 ||
     strcmp(nextWordDict, strcat(nextWord, ".")) == 0 ||
     strcmp(nextWordDict, strcat(nextWord, "?")) == 0 ||
     strcmp(nextWordDict, strcat(nextWord, "!")) == 0 ||
     strcmp(nextWordDict, strcat(nextWord, ",")) == 0) {
        count++;
 }
```

to the code producing 17 for Mars to try and account for cases with trailing punctuation, and there was no change. Still 17.

**EDIT2**:

As John Bollinger correctly points out below, this code does nothing because the string buffered into nextWord would already have the trailing punctuation, and the code would only be adding more. This is faulty thinking on my part.

Comment: Dunno, but it's easy to find out. Just `printf("%s\n",nextWord)` after every `fscanf`. Redirect the output to a couple of files and compare the files.

Comment: Also, in the working code, you can combine the two `fscanf` into one using this format string `"%*[^a-zA-Z]%80[a-zA-Z]"`. As I'm writing this, it occurs to me that you may have a buffer overflow. The format string in the non-working code should be `"%80s"` to limit the word size to 80.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The change to "%80s" yields the same result

Comment: No, you cannot safely combine the two `scanf()` calls into one.  The resulting behavior differs when the first edit descriptor does not match an input item.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrect when you say that the command ...

```
$ grep -o -w 'Mars' TripToMars.txt | wc -w
```

... "finds only instances of 'Mars' as a standalone word", or at least that statement is misleading in context.  The command finds instances of "Mars" that are not part of a larger word, where a "word" is defined as a contiguous string of letters, digits, and/or underscores.  In particular, it will match "Mars" where it is followed by a punctuation mark, which conflicts with what you seem to be claiming.

But what is the difference between your two scanning approaches? Well, this ...

```
while (fscanf(textToSearch, "%*[^a-zA-Z]"),
        fscanf(textToSearch, "%80[a-zA-Z]", nextWord) > 0) { /* ... */ }
```

... scans zero or more characters that are not Latin letters, ignoring whether any are matched and whether any input error occurs, then scans a contiguous sequence of up to 80 Latin letters, recording that sequence in the `nextWord` buffer.

On the other hand, this ...

```
while(1) {
    d = fscanf(textToSearch, "%s", nextWord);
    if (d == EOF) break;
}
```

... ignores leading whitespace, then scans the next contiguous string of non-whitespace into `nextWord`.

The two differ significantly in what they do with characters that are neither Latin letters nor whitespace: the former ignores them, whereas the latter includes them in `nextWord`.  When you then compare `nextWord` with the string `"Mars"`, the latter misses on

> Going to Mars.

and

> The name "Mars"

and

> Is there water on Mars?

because the adjacent punctuation is included in the comparison.  Your text is quite likely to have many constructions similar to those, and your `grep` commands do not demonstrate otherwise.

Comment: Oof, I had the wrong idea about the -w flag for grep, thank you for correcting that for me.

I went ahead and added code to include the trailing punctuation (see edit above) and I get the same result of 17.

Comment: Your logic is backward there.  I'm positing that in many cases `nextWord` *already* has punctuation marks on one or both sides.  Adding more is not going to improve your matching.  Moreover, `strcat()` modifies its left argument, so you end up appending a whole string of punctuation marks.  And you also need to worry about punctuation on the left.  Why not just use your first approach, which works, and does a good job of expressing what you actually want?

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't thinking clearly about what that code was doing. It makes a lot of sense now. I use my first approach, but I was just trying to understand why the second did not work. Thanks for clearing it up :)

Comment: neither of the two while loops is foolproof.  suggest inputting the file character by char using a state maching.  when a 'M' is found change to second  state, looking for 'a', etc.  and at each failure, step back to the first state, using the current character.   repeat until EOF.  if a state is reached where the whole 'Mars' string is found, then bump the counter.

Comment: @user3629249, what problem do you see with the first loop, other than the 80-character word-size limit?